# How to "mark" multiple "words" in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I hope I explain this correctly.

Using notepad++ I am trying to "mark" multiple words. I tried adding a `,` between each word I am looking for in the "find what:" portion of "mark" but with no success. I could do this one at a time but I want to mark about 50 words and that would take too long

Example:

I want to mark `yahoo`, `candy` and `goku` all at once.

Is this possible with notepad++?

Answer (score 5):

This answer is similar to nixda's

Using the Find dialog in the Search menu:

1. Click the Mark tab
2. In the Find What textbox type the regular expression `(Yahoo|Goku|Candy)`
3. In the Search Mode group select Regular Expressions
4. Click Mark All

As far as I'm aware this doesn't require the RegEx Helper, although I could be wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

With the [RegEx helper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppregexhelper/) plugin you can use the search pattern

```
(yahoo|candy|goku)
```

[image]

Unfortunately you can only *mark* them, not replace them at once.

---

Alternatively you could use [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/3)

[image]